# Is it possible to add a field to every document in a collection in MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Is it possible to add a field to every document in a collection in MongoDB Compass? Or is this something that has to be done in the shell?

Answer (score 9):

There is no option in Compass to update all documents with a new field; Compass's "Document tab" has option to modify a document's field *or* add a new field ([modify](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/documents/modify/) one document at a time).

This is to be done from the *mongo shell* or your favorite programming language.

From the shell, to update all documents in a collection with a new field use the [db.collection.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method. For example, `db.test.updateMany( { }, { $set: { new_field: "initial value" } } )`.

Once, the documents are updated, these can be viewed from the Compass; just do a *refresh* in the *Documents* view / tab.

Comment: this simply works